# Google index different URL from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, google-indexing-api

I'm using wordpress with woocommerce.
The url I am using for my site is: 
https://example.com/product/product-name/

But google is indexing this url as:
https://example.com/product-name/

How can I solve this?

Comment: Does your website have a sitemap.xml?  are you using Google Search Console and have submitted your sitemap there?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single page accessible by multiple URLs, or different pages with similar content (for example, a page with both a mobile and a desktop version), Google sees these as duplicate versions of the same page. Google will choose one URL as the canonical version and crawl that, and all other URLs will be considered duplicate URLs and crawled less often.

You can find more information here https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en